# regional tenant based routing in multitenant saas

Tags: spring-boot, azure, multi-tenant, saas

We are working on to deploy a saas application in two region (us,eu), and we have only single domain : "ourdomain.com".
And we want to give a unique url to each tenant example tenat1.ourdomain.com  or tenant2.ourdomain.com, but We do not want subdomain like tenat1.us.ourdomain.com tenat3.eu.ourdomain.com  tenat1.ourdomain.com tenat1.ourdomain.eu.
we have 10,0000 of tenant we are plaining to go live, as we want to automate customer/tenant onboarding, on registration page customer can select subdomain name and region, so as soon as customer register they get a unique name and they can able to login.
We are using azure app service, we have two app service one in us region and another is in eu region,
We are using wildcard certificate, with azure frotndoor.  Now the challenge is  when a new tenant register how we can do region based mapping or where we should do this is it viable to  do 10000 of mapping ?

It would be really great if any one have previous experience into deploy b2b saas in multiple region with this kind of subdomain pattern.

Now the challenge is  when a new tenant register how we can do region based mapping or where we should do this is it viable to  do 10000 of mapping